# Import of Redis dump fails with 'unknown command'. Why?

Tags: redis, migration

I got the `dump.rdb` file from the Redis running on my server.

When I try to load the dump in my local Redis

```
redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 < dump.rdb
```

I get these errors:

```
(error) ERR unknown command `REDIS0010�`, with args beginning with: `redis-ver7.0.12�`, 
(error) ERR unknown command `redis-bits�@�ctime�(�dused-mem�`, with args beginning with: 
(error) ERR unknown command `�Ʈ�`, with args beginning with: 
(error) ERR unknown command `�`, with args beginning with: `u�`,
```

Both Redis versions are 7.x.
What do I need to do to make it work?

Edit: The server is running the 'normal' Redis docker image (`redis:7.0`) without any customization.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have costume commands in your instance? if so, make sure you have your module loaded to the new one

Comment: *How* are you trying to load it? This looks like you're feeding a raw dump to the CLI.

Comment: @tadman Improved the question. Are there different types for dumps?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to load an external snapshot file into a standard Redis Docker container, is to create a volume and mount it.

If the snapshot file is named `dump.rdb` and it's located in local folder `~/backup`, you can start the container with `docker run -d -v ~/backup/dump.rdb:/data/dump.rdb redis:7.0` and all data in the snapshot should be available in the Redis instance in the container.